# Did Emmanuel Macron say France deserved acts of terrorism?

Tags: politics, quotes

I've seen this image floating around on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/IndependentUK/photos/a.170859326262998.47609.136101146405483/1710065022342413/?type=3&theater) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/LadyMSunshine/status/856213924529790980):

[image]

> We have been horribly Islamophobic, and we deserve each act of terrorism that is inflicted upon us. - Emmanuel Macron

Did Macron really say this, or something like it?

Comment: Sorry but this "meme" is not a "meme", it only has a few retweets and shares...

Comment: @Sklivvz The Facebook post has 434 likes or other reactions.

Comment: @Sklivvz Sorry, I used "meme" in the colloquial sense of "an image macro". Does editing it to "image" instead of "meme" resolve the issue you have?

Comment: @Sklivvz I think you may have only looked at the metrics for the tweet.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I looked at both and I think that 400 shares is really not much at all.

Answer (score 13):

**Probably not**:

I couldn't find any evidence he said this nor any evidence that might suggest he hold views which similar to one in the quote. I did find the following:

Assuming that "we" refers to the French then we find that the quote is contradicting other (actual) statements he made:

> **Les Français ne sont pas islamophobes, mais l’islam radical fait peur.**
>
> Avec les Britanniques et les Allemands, les Français sont le peuple d’Europe où les opinions antimusulmanes sont les moins répandues, et les plus nombreux à penser que les musulmans veulent s’intégrer. Mais les opinions défavorables ont progressé après les attentats.

Translation:

> **The French are not Islamophobes, but radical Islam causes fear.**
>
> With the Britons and the Germans, the French are the people of Europe where anti-Muslim opinions are the least wide-spread, and the most numerous in thinking that Muslims want to integrate themselves. But unfavourable opinions have grown after the [terrorist or murder] attempts.
>
> — Mr. Macron, on his [website](https://en-marche.fr/emmanuel-macron/le-programme/questions-religieuses-et-laicite)

<sup>Source: [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/05/world/europe/emmanuel-macron-marine-le-pen-quotes.html?_r=0)</sup>